# MySQLI: Transactions, allow PHP to handle or in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, transactions

On the subject of Transactions, is it in better practice to allow the MySQli Library to handle transactions using the functions:

`mysqli_begin_transaction()`, `mysqli_rollback()` and `mysqli_commit()`

or allow a transaction to be handled directly in MySQli using the `query()` or `prepare()`?

Comment: You need to use mysql, mysqli or PDO to execute queries.

Comment: @RonakPatel This comment has confused me. The MySQli Library in PHP contains functions that can be used to handle transactions. The question is revolving around whether it would be best to use these functions or handle it directly in a prepared statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference between the API calls and using SQL statements, because the internals of mysqli (and mysqlnd) just form SQL statements and execute them with query().

The only difference is that if you want to use options like `START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT` or `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT` or `COMMIT AND CHAIN`, it's easier to write it yourself than to use the *undocumented* `$flags` argument to the mysqli functions.

---

Re your comment:

There's no functional difference, the only difference is the number of keystrokes.

The API methods have an advantage for developers who use a code editor with code completion, because they can quickly produce the code that invokes API methods. If you write SQL statements in strings, then you must type those yourself, so you can't use code-completion and if you aren't a good typist you might introduce typos.

If you define PHP constants for commonly-used SQL statements, this would address both code-completion and typos.

Comment: So inall, it's easier to maintain/debug and develop on  a transaction statement written in just `$mysqli->query` or `$mysqli->prepare`?